# Django: Combine ListView with UpdateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I created a ListView with a slug that filters all attendees with a certain order_reference. I want to create a second ListView where it is possible to update all these attendees (`fields: first_name, last_name, email`) at once. Basically, a form with a **Save All** button to update the database entries. I started to try it with UpdateView, but failed with that as I have several entries in my queryset. Anyone did that before and can lead me the right way to achieve that?

views.py:

```
class AssignAttendee(ListView):
    allow_empty = False
    template_name = 'attendees/assign_attendee.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
            order__access_key=self.kwargs['access_key'],
        )
```